# Cisco ASA network object host changes with NAT

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, nat, firewall, cisco-commands

How do I take this:

```
object network obj-nat_DNS1
 host 10.128.33.11
object network obj-nat_DNS2
 host 10.128.33.12
```

And change the hosts to different IPs?  I'm not trying to delete the network objects, just modifying them. I tried this:

```
object network obj-nat_DNS1
 no host 10.128.33.11
 host 10.128.33.21
object network obj-nat_DNS2
 no host 10.128.33.12
 host 10.129.22.22
```

And I got:

```
ERROR: unable to delete object (obj-nat_DNS1). object is being used.
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you cannot do this right away.  You have to temporarily negate everywhere the object is being used.

My advice would be to copy the commands where the objects are being used, negate them and do the changes to the object.

Once done, you can copy the initial command from the text file to the ASA back again.